# Not able to create this table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ddl

I am trying to create this table in my database with no luck at all. All my tables look the same, but this one is giving me trouble.

I am using Notepad to type, then copying the code to the MySQL 5.7 command line.

```
CREATE TABLE Order Parts (
'ord_id' INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
'part_id' INT(7) NOT NULL,
inv_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
ord_shipdate DATE NOT NULL,
ord_received DATE NOT NULL,
ord_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ord_cost DECIMAL NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Recommendations

1. Use a table name without spaces.
2. Remove the apostrophes from 'ord_id' and 'part_id'.

#### Solution

```
CREATE TABLE OrderParts ( 
  ord_id INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, part_id INT(7) NOT NULL
, inv_id INT(7) NOT NULL
, ord_shipdate DATE NOT NULL
, ord_received DATE NOT NULL
, ord_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, ord_cost DECIMAL NOT NULL 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are going to use a space in the name of a table it needs to be wrapped in brackets []. That being said, it is not suggested to have spaces in the name of a table.
- I'm not sure why you're trying to define the length of an int column, but just delcaring it as INT is enough.
- AUTO_INCREMENT is not supported in SQL Server. Use Identity instead.

The following declaration worked on my machine (SQL Server 2016 SP1 installed)

```
CREATE TABLE [Order Parts] ( 
  ord_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY Identity(1,1)
, part_id INT NOT NULL
, inv_id INT NOT NULL
, ord_shipdate DATE NOT NULL
, ord_received DATE NOT NULL
, ord_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, ord_cost DECIMAL NOT NULL 
);
```

Check out this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777734/how-do-i-add-a-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server-database

EDIT-- Just noticed this was tagged as SQL and not SQL-Server. If you are using MySQL, look at this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Order Parts` ( 
  ord_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
, part_id INT NOT NULL
, inv_id INT NOT NULL
, ord_shipdate DATE NOT NULL
, ord_received DATE NOT NULL
, ord_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
, ord_cost DECIMAL NOT NULL 
);
```

Answer (score -2):

specify the PRIMARY KEY at the end of table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderParts (
ord_id INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
part_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
inv_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
ord_shipdate DATE NOT NULL,
ord_received DATE NOT NULL,
ord_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ord_cost DECIMAL NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ord_id)
);
```

Comment: Both ways of creating a primary key work fine. I don't think this is the issue.